# Linear programming with cupy

Tags: python, linear-programming, cupy

I am trying to improve codes efficiency with cupy. But I find no ways to carry linear programming within cupy. This problem comes from the following parts:

```
N = hull_points.shape[0]
c = ones(N)
A_eq = concatenate((hull_points, ones((N, 1))),
                   1).T   # rows are x, y, z, 1
b_eq = concatenate((pnt, (1,)))
result = linprog(c, A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=b_eq)
```

Is there something I can use directly? Or the only way out is to implement a linear programming package based on cupy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve seen papers that propose to use GPU for linear programming. Some of them even reported outstanding improvement.
But from what I saw, they compare their GPU implementation of the simplex method with their sequential implementation, not with Gurobi, Cplex, or even CLP.
And I never heard about an efficient GPU-base LP solver that beats good LP solvers.
Such flagman like Gurobi does not support GPU.
And I know there are some doubts that GPU actually can help in large-scale LP.

- Large-scale LPs are sparse, and GPU is not good for sparse.
- Optimization in general is mostly a sequential process (paralleling in modern LP solvers is very specific and cannot utilize GPU).

If you want to try to implement your own GPU-base LP solver, I encourage you to try. Whatever you get it would be a great experience.

But if you only need to speed up your solution process then get a different solver. Linprog from SciPy may be a good choice to prototype. But GLPK or CLP/CBC  will give you much better speed. You can invoke them through Pyomo or PULP.

Comment: I fully agree on GPU vs. Simplex/LP. Only one remark: Nowadays, `linprog` supports `highs-ds` ([HiGHS](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/hall/HiGHS/#guide)) which usually beats glpk easily and competes with Clp ([Benchmark](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/lpsimp.html)). It's also very actively developed.

Comment: Very inspiring answer. I have spent several days on the GPU code and just finished a test on it, except this part. The result shows that the GPU code is less efficiency on my problem than CPU. 
But I am still interested in carrying this out. So may I ask which course should I take to improve my understanding on the mathematical background of such problem? Convex optimization or?

Comment: Simplex-style solvers are a self-standing research topic and even the top-tier open-source / community-projects like CoinOR Clp / HiGHS contain ideas never published in books or papers. This is a very specialized area with a few experts (in-between math and computer-science). You will find GPU attempts and also (see HiGHS' background) parallelization attempts with academic papers published, explaining some hurdles (Simplex vs. Parallelization in general). If you don't want to spend months to exploit your specific problem (chance of failure), just go with state-of-the art: cpu-based solvers.

Comment: Imho, if i would tackle some LP with GPUs, i would go for interior-point solvers (which are known to be much more parallelism-friendly; and if you already got a sparse solver for linear systems: maybe by CUDA, those are much easier to implement). This is another self-standing research topic, but there is a good book named "Primal-Dual Interior-Point Methods".